# A simple inequality with logarithms and exponential

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponentiation

I want to prove that for $k>0$:

$ 2^k \geq \frac{-1}{\log_2(1-\frac{1}{2^k})}$

I've plotted both functions and it seems to be the case for k>0.

In fact, it would also be nice to see that:

$ \frac{-1}{\log_2(1-\frac{1}{2^k})} \geq 2^{k-1}$

Thank you!

Comment: Are the logs $\log_2$ instead of $log2$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is $\log_2$. I've corrected the question.

Comment: $$ \log_2 \left({ \frac{2^k - 1}{2^k} }\right) = \log_2 \left( {2^k - 1} \right) - \log_2 \left(2^k\right)$$

Comment: Thank you "Back in a Flash", the second term reduces to k. But now what?

Comment: I reached this: $\log_2(2^k-1)^{2k} \ge \log_2 2^{k2^k} -1$

Answer (score 3):

With $t = 1 - 2^{-k}$ (so $0 < t < 1$ for $k > 0$), your inequality becomes 
$1/(1-t) \ge -1/\log_2(t)$, or $\log_2(t) \le -1+t$.  In fact $\log_2(t) = \ln(t)/\ln(2)$ and $\ln(2) < 1$ so $\log_2(t) < \ln(t)$, and $\ln(t) \le -1+t$.

Your "it would be nice" is not true for $0 < k < 1$.  It is true for $k \ge 1$.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Robert! How trivial it seems when one sees the solution :-(